# trying to send emails in bulk, but there is something wrong with my smtp configuration

Tags: smtp, powershell-ise

I'm unemployed and looking for a job. Therefore I need to send emails to a lot of companies. This case is about unsolicited applications. The body of the email is the same, but the recipent is obviously different from mail to mail. So I wondered if you could do this in Powershell. Did a bit of research, and came up with [this](https://pastebin.com/yBcYDPQc) (A test, so not filled with the right information). However, I get the following error: "the smtp server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated 5.7.57". And I'm positive that I've entered the correct credentials. Is it a wrong smtp server, or do I don't have the permissions to send, and in that case should I send from a gmail?

Comment: If you have Office, it is much easier to do in Word+Excel. You can create a list in excel, and create an email in Word, then use mail merge to send emails.